# Add subscriber to mailchimp with python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mailchimp

What is the simplest way - or library - to add a subscriber to mailchimp with python 2.5 on google app engine?

Comment: Did you check the mailchimp webservice API for Python? http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/ What did you try?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[mailsnake](https://github.com/michaelhelmick/python-mailsnake) and [PostMonkey](https://github.com/ericrasmussen/postmonkey/) both require [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library, which dropped python 2.5 support with 0.10.1.

The simplest path seems to be [chimpy](http://code.google.com/p/chimpy/).

Code Sample:

```
from chimpy import chimpy

chimp = chimpy.Connection('MAILCHIMP_APIKEY')
chimp.list_subscribe('your_list_id', self.request.get('email'), {'FIRST': '', 'LAST': ''}, double_optin=False)
```

Comment: Does this code actually work? We are getting a key error for the email field.

Comment: This code works for us for adding subscribers on appengine as of December 2017. Just vendor in the code as described by google for third party software.

Answer (score 1):

The MailChimp API has all the details for the functionality that you want.

- API Documentation : http://apidocs.mailchimp.com
- Python libraries: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/ and go to Python section
- Subscribe an email to a list : http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listsubscribe.func.php

Hope this helps.

Comment: They list there 6 python libraries ... my question is which on of this is the simplest do just drag and drop into a project which is deployed on app egine

Comment: I have not used any of the Python libraries. Maybe someone else can pitch in here.

Comment: thx anyway. I went down the trial and error route until I found something that works :)

Comment: Can you tell us which one you went for in the end